# ROS node reading from bag not exiting correctly

Tags: ros, c++

I need a C++ script which can read through bags and do some processing, basically the structure is going to be

```cpp
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  ros::init(argc, argv, node_name);
  ros::NodeHandle nh("~");

  // do stuff

  return 0;
}
```

where I create the nodehandle only to have a parameter server. I explicitly don't want this to have subscribers, as it'll be much faster just reading the bag and processing.

The problem is that this does not exit correctly, when ctrl+C the program keeps going and upon reaching `return 0;` it requires a ctrl+C for the launch file to close out on the terminal. How can I fix this? I'd like to avoid wrapping the entirety of `// do stuff` with a `while (ros::ok())`

Edit: The script responded fine to ctrl+C when it was `rosrun`, but launching it (which I need to for easy including yaml file, causes this behavior.

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! Please update your question as it is difficult to understand your question. The tiny code you shared provides no information. I suggest sharing a [minimum working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Thank you for your kind cooperation.

Comment: There isn't a whole lot more to it, theres no spin or any normal ros content (lik pub/sub). It's just creating a node, accessing params, reading the bag file, and doing some processing. 100% offline

Comment: And the problems are that ctrl+C doesn't interrupt the `// do stuff` section, nor does it end the launch file when the C++ script finishes. There's really not much more to it than that. What part is it you're not understanding?

Comment: Try `required="true"` in the launch file http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node#Attributes

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you'd like to avoid the `while(ros::ok())` pattern because you're reading from a bag file, so rather than running in a loop you plan to step through each individual message and then exit when complete (or sooner, if ctrl-c is detected).

We can use `ros::ok()` outside of a while loop. Here's a modified version of the [rosbag code API example](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API) that does that:

```
#include <rosbag/bag.h>
#include <rosbag/view.h>
#include <std_msgs/Int32.h>

rosbag::Bag bag;
bag.open("test.bag");  // BagMode is Read by default

for(rosbag::MessageInstance const m: rosbag::View(bag))
{
  // read data
  std_msgs::Int32::ConstPtr i = m.instantiate<std_msgs::Int32>();
  if (i != nullptr)
    std::cout << i->data << std::endl;

  // exit loop if node is told to shut down
  if (!ros::ok())
    break;
}

bag.close();
```